# iconAnchor and infowindowanchor for a given image

Tags: google-maps

What is iconAnchor and infowindowanchor for google map marker below:
http://storelocator.gizmocode.com/admin/marker/03.png

I still don't understand what is 'The pixel coordinate relative to the top left corner of the icon image at which this icon is anchored to the map' so I give an image and ask for iconAnchor and infowindowanchor...

The image size is : 45 width x 66 height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That image](http://storelocator.gizmocode.com/admin/marker/03.png) has these dimensions: 45px × 66px

The anchor point is usually in the middle of the bottom (the point): new google.maps.Point(22,66)

The infoWindow anchor is usually at the top middle: new google.maps.Point(22,0);
(but you could put it wherever makes sense to you).

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_icon-complex_SOa.html) (based off [the example in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex), with your icon)

Comment: How big do you want it to be?  The ["default marker"](http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png) is 20px × 34px